Access Violation exception when calling DLL function loaded with boost import_alias
I am trying to call a function from a DLL. The API for the DLL looks like this:
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined _MSC_VER || defined __MINGW32__
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
#else
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define API extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #else
        #define API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #endif
#endif


API void* construct(const char* initString);

I am loading that function call using boost, and then trying to call it:
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>


typedef void* (ConstructT)(const char*);

int main() {
    boost::function<ConstructT> constructFunc = boost::dll::import_alias<ConstructT>(
        "TestPluginDll.dll",
        "construct",
        boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations | boost::dll::load_mode::load_with_altered_search_path
    );
    
    std::string initArg = "hello";
    void* pluginInstance = constructFunc(initArg.c_str());
    std::cout << pluginInstance << std::endl;
}

However, it is failing on the call of the constructFunc, throwing an error at the following code in boost/dll/import.hpp:
        // Compilation error at this point means that imported function
        // was called with unmatching parameters.
        //
        // Example:
        // auto f = dll::import_symbol<void(int)>("function", "lib.so");
        // f("Hello");  // error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'
        // f(1, 2);     // error: too many arguments to function
        // f();         // error: too few arguments to function
        template <class... Args>
        inline auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
            -> decltype( (*f_)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...) )
        {
            return (*f_)(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
        }

Why is this failing? The type of std::string.c_str() is const char*, so it seems like it is the correct type.
For reference, my DLL code looks like this:
#include <plugin_interface.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>


class MyPlugin {
public:
    MyPlugin() {}
};


extern "C" API void* construct(const char* initString) {
    MyPlugin* plugin = new MyPlugin();
    return static_cast<void*>(plugin);
}

The exception:
Exception has occurred: W32/0xC0000005
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF77B713633 in tmp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.



@user7860670 There are no build error messages, the error is at runtime, It just exits the program without outputting anything, it just breaks on that part of the code when I run it in debug mode

auto f = dll::import_symbol<void(int)> why are you declaring it as taking an int ?

If you get a crash it's not a compilation error. Where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables? Dop you have any error checking to make sure that the DLL and the function are properly loaded and fetched?

@AhmedAEK That is the example ontop of the code, in the boost source code

@Someprogrammerdude I only included that as it was what was said on top of the function call that is throwing the error in boost, sorry I will change the title of the question. I believe that if there is an error loading the DLL function, the program will crash on the creation of the constructFunc  variable

If you are using Visual Studio Community / Ent you can have it stop on the access violation and examine the variables and callstack to attempt to see what the issue is.

Is the dllPath correct? Is it a relative path, and the DLL is not where you expect it to be? If you use a full absolute path, does it work then?

throwing an error Which error? You have shown where but not what.

@Someprogrammerdude The dll is next to the executable which is being ran, it seems like the DLL is being loaded but the call is not working for some reason. If I change the name of the dll to something else, it throws an error on the boost::dll::import_alias<ConstructT> call, same if I change the name its trying to load

@user7860670, they are within some other code, but I just made them as an example script, I will modify the question to wrap that in an int main() call. I am not sure how to best show the whole stack trace and variables for the call? It is really in a class which does the same thing on initialization

@user7860670 I've added a screenshot of the exception, it is an access violation but I am not sure why. I will edit the title now.

Please post a [mre]. The shown main.cpp doesn't have 17 lines of the code. Ensure the app binds the actual .dll built with the shown code. You seem to use mingw on Windows. Then check the loaded C++ runtime.

@user7860670 I've added the test dll as a build dependency of my executable, and made it so that it gets copied to the same location as the exe after building so i'm pretty sure that is fine (unfortunately). The creation of the constructFunc variable passes fine, when I introduce any errors (like the name of the dll being wrong), the boost::dll::import_alias fails so I am fairly certain it is loading the dll ok

I will try make a full project reproducable example, I thought there was enough in the question to see if there was any obvious mistakes from me but looks like it needs a full example

After even further investigation i've realized that boost is actually working as intended. The problem is caused by wrong usage of boost::dll::import_alias. It is supposed to be used only with special symbols exported from library via BOOST_DLL_ALIAS macro. alias in this context is a variable in global namespace with plain name containing a pointer to actually exported deeply nested function. see Factory method in plugin
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp> // for BOOST_DLL_ALIAS   
#include "../tutorial_common/my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace my_namespace {

class my_plugin_aggregator : public my_plugin_api {
    float aggr_;
    my_plugin_aggregator() : aggr_(0) {}

public:
    std::string name() const {
        return "aggregator";
    }

    float calculate(float x, float y) {
        aggr_ += x + y;
        return aggr_;
    }

    // Factory method
    static boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_aggregator> create() {
        return boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_aggregator>(
            new my_plugin_aggregator()
        );
    }
};


BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(
    my_namespace::my_plugin_aggregator::create, // <-- this function is exported with...
    create_plugin                               // <-- ...this alias name
)

} // namespace my_namespace

Since construct is just a regular function in global namespace it can be imported with boost::dll::import_symbol
boost::function<ConstructT> constructFunc = boost::dll::import_symbol<ConstructT>(
        "TestPluginDll.dll",
        "construct",
        boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations | boost::dll::load_mode::load_with_altered_search_path
    );



Thanks for the update, I was using the BOOST_DLL_ALIAS before, but I had to change to a C compatible API and I didnt know I had to use import_symbol instead

In addition to the bug restriction noted by @user7860670, this typedef is incorrect:
typedef void* (ConstructT)(const char*);

It needs an extern "C".  Language linkage is part of a function's type.
extern "C" {
  typedef void* (ConstructT)(const char*);
}

While omitting the language linkage may work in practice on many toolchains, formally it leads to undefined behavior at the point of actually using the function pointer (or reference) to call the function.
